# Highcharts: Using datetime axis for a full year when data values lie on the end of a month?

Tags: highcharts

Fiddle to illustrate the problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/TristanCrawford/Lwf19q8a/22/

I'm passing a series of `[timestamp, value]` pairs for January-December, however the timestamps are for the last day of each respective month.

What I'd like is for the ticks/axis labels to also be January through December, but also for the points to be centered on those ticks. The problem is that, since the timestamps are at the end of the month, the labels actually end up being February through January of the following year.

I can get around this by just using a category axis instead of a datetime axis, however this introduces a problem with CSV exporting, where dates just end up being the raw timestamp (even when specifying the dateFormat in the exporting options)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `xAxis.tickPositioner` to achieve that.

Example config:

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    labels: {
      format: '{value:%b}',
            x: 25
    },
    startOnTick: true,
    endOnTick: true,
    showLastLabel: false,
    tickPositioner: function() {
      let positions = [],
        month = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
        positions.push(Date.UTC(2023, month, 15));
        month++;
      }
      return positions;
    }
  },
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3peo5jdf/

API Reference:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositioner